# Updating Oracle XMLType Column Content For a Given Value

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, xquery, updatexml

I have a table, SECTION_ANSWER, in an Oracle 11g database which has an XMLType column. The XML is pretty simple, it follows the structure:

```
<section sectionID="1">
    <question questionID="1" questionType="text">
        <answer>Green</answer>
    </question>
    <question questionID="2" questionType="multiselect">
        <answer>101</answer>
        <answer>102</answer>
        <answer>105</answer>
        <answer>107</answer>
    </question>
</section>
```

I need to update the '105' answer to be '205.'  I have done something similar in the past using UPDATEXML. For example if I was to update questionID 1 which only has one answer, I could do something like:

```
UPDATE SECTION_ANSWER sa
SET sa.section_answerxml = updatexml(sa.section_answerxml, '//section[@sectionID="1"]/question[@questionID="1"]/answer/text()', 'BLUE')
```

However, I'm having trouble this time updating questionID 2, since there are multiple answer nodes and I do not know which node the content that needs to be updated will be in.  Can anyone shed any light on how to perform this kind of update?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this will update all answer nodes for question 2 that has 105.

```
UPDATE SECTION_ANSWER sa
SET sa.section_answerxml = updatexml(sa.section_answerxml,
'//section[@sectionID="1"]/question[@questionID="2"]/answer[text()="105"]/text()', '205')
```

or you can update by position

```
UPDATE SECTION_ANSWER sa
SET sa.section_answerxml = updatexml(sa.section_answerxml,
'//section[@sectionID="1"]/question[@questionID="2"]/answer[position()=3]/text()', '205')
```

Comment: Thanks edgar!!  I was not aware that you could specify [text()="105"].  That resolved my issue :)